# elasticsearch update a source field without re-indexing entire document

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have document {customerID: 111, name: bob, approved: yes}

The field "approved" is not indexed. I have a mapping set as "approved": { "type" : "string", "index" : "no" }

So only the fields "customerID" and "name" are indexed.

How can I update just the approved field in the _source without re-indexing the entire document? I can pass the partial document to update such as {approved: no}

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is [partial update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html). The problem is this will actually perform delete+put+index implicitly, but you just leave this hustle for ES and will not lose time for network roundtrip. Probably ES will optimize such query (in case of unindexed fields, but AFAIK it doesn't do such for now)

```
POST so/t3/1
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "id": 1,
  "approved": "no"
}

GET so/t3/_search

POST so/t3/1/_update
{
  "doc": {
    "approved": "yes"
  }
}

{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "so",
            "_type": "t3",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Bob",
               "id": 1,
               "approved": "yes"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```